# Mojo-lang error about fn, recursion factorial code

Tags: mojolang

I'm a student. I am currently doing research about how fast Mojo Lang is. I want to run the recursion code, and compare it to python. I decided to write a simple recursion code, and an error occurred. Please help me.

I tried to make a factorial code. If i run the code, it prints me a factorial of num variable.

here is my code

```
fn fact(n:Int):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fact(n-1)

var num = 14

if num<0:
    print("sry")
elif num ==0:
    print("1")
else:
    print(fact(num))
```

and this is the error

```
error: Expression [19]:7:16: cannot implicitly convert 'Int' value to 'None' in return value
        return 1
               ^

error: Expression [19]:9:22: ambiguous call to 'fact', each candidate requires 0 implicit conversions, disambiguate with an explicit cast
        return n*fact(n-1)
                 ~~~~^~~~~

Expression [19]:5:1: candidate declared here
fn fact(n:Int):
^

Expression [14]:5:1: candidate declared here
def fact(n:Int):
^

error: Expression [19]:29:19: ambiguous call to 'fact', each candidate requires 0 implicit conversions, disambiguate with an explicit cast
        print(fact(num))
              ~~~~^~~~~

Expression [19]:5:1: candidate declared here
fn fact(n:Int):
^

Expression [14]:5:1: candidate declared here
def fact(n:Int):
^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error message tells you the problem: the function is meant to return `None` and you try to return an `Int`. This should hint you how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation of `fn`:

> a missing return type specifier is interpreted as returning None instead of an unknown return type.

So you should specify the return type for the `fact` function as `Int`, because the interpreter assumes `None` and complains when the function return an `Int`.

```
fn fact(n:Int) -> Int:
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fact(n-1)
```